# MYSQL Nested Queries

Tags: php, mysql

The purpose of asking this question is just to learn how to make nested queries in MYSQL.

1) What is wrong with the following query?

```
"SELECT tblwriter.writer_alias, tblwriter.writer_first_name, COUNT(tblordersub.suborder_alias) AS totalOrders FROM tblwriter, tblordersub WHERE tblwriter.writer_isactive = 1 AND tblordersub.writer_alias = tblwriter.writer_alias"
```

2) Can there be a better solution for the following nest of MYSQL queries?

```
$currentorders = $db->rawQuery("SELECT order_title,order_alias FROM tblorder WHERE company_id=? AND YEAR(order_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(order_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())",$params);
$orderssummary = array();
if(!empty($currentorders)){
    foreach($currentorders as $corder){
        $param = array($corder["order_alias"]);
        $oprice = $db->rawQuery("SELECT payment_amount FROM tblpayment WHERE payment_status = 1 AND writer_alias IS NULL AND order_alias=?",$param);
        $itssuborders = $db->rawQuery("SELECT suborder_alias FROM tblordersub WHERE order_alias=?",$param);
        $thesuborders = array_implode("",",",$itssuborders);
        $cost = $db->rawQuery("SELECT SUM(payment_amount) AS total_subtotal FROM tblpayment WHERE writer_alias IS NOT NULL AND suborder_alias IN (".$thesuborders.")");
        $orderssummary[] = array("title"=>$corder["order_title"],"price"=>$oprice[0]["payment_amount"],"cost"=>$cost[0]["total_subtotal"]);
    }
}
```

3) Is there any way to combine the following three queries into 1?

```
"SELECT SUM(payment_amount) AS totalAmount FROM tblpayment WHERE company_id=? AND payment_status = 1 AND order_alias IS NOT NULL AND YEAR(payment_add_datetime) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(payment_add_datetime) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)"
"SELECT SUM(payment_amount) AS totalAmount FROM tblpayment WHERE company_id=? AND payment_status = 0 AND writer_alias IS NOT NULL AND YEAR(payment_add_datetime) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(payment_add_datetime) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)"
"SELECT SUM(payment_amount) AS totalAmount FROM tblpayment WHERE company_id=? AND payment_status = 1 AND writer_alias IS NOT NULL AND YEAR(payment_add_datetime) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(payment_add_datetime) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)"
```

4) Same as 2nd question, is there any way to combine the following queries into 1 query?

```
$biggest_customers = $db->rawQuery("SELECT payment_user_id, SUM(payment_amount) AS totalEARNED FROM tblpayment WHERE writer_alias IS NULL AND order_alias IS NOT NULL GROUP BY payment_user_id ORDER BY totalEARNED DESC LIMIT 10");
for($i=0;$i<count($biggest_customers);$i++){
    $params = array($biggest_customers[$i]["payment_user_id"]);
    $customerinformation = $db->rawQuery('SELECT customer_alias FROM tblcustomer WHERE user_id=?',$params);
    $biggest_customers[$i]["customer_alias"] = $customerinformation[0]["customer_alias"];
    unset($biggest_customers[$i]["payment_user_id"]);
}
```

Hope to learn somethings!!

Comment: first query: no group by. and i think you're asking more about joins than nested queries

Comment: and please use explicit JOIN syntax. In fact, before going too much further, you should really take a crash course in JOINs. They're pretty easy and essential to improving performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See aggregate queries
2. See JOINs
3. See CASE statements/PIVOT TABLE queries
4. See JOIN again

Answer (score 0):

you can not use the COUNT() statement (aggregation query) without a GROUP BY when selecting multiple columns. You also should rather use a join statement to select values from different tables. Something like this maybe:

```
SELECT tblwriter.writer_alias, tblwriter.writer_first_name, COUNT(tblordersub.suborder_alias) AS totalOrders 
FROM tblwriter 
INNER JOIN tblordersub ON (tblordersub.writer_alias = tblwriter.writer_alias) 
WHERE tblwriter.writer_isactive = 1
GROUP BY tblordersub.suborder_alias
```

By just using `FROM tblwriter, tblordersub` in your query you are creating a cross join, which is the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the data in your tables. You probably don't want that.